# Can we use logical operators with the return statement

Tags: python

Can I use the not operator in this case and output the else as false using not operator

```
 # NEW TO PYTHON
 def is_positive(number):
  if number > 0:
    return bool(number)
  else:
    return not bool(number)
```

Comment: Yes, you can (didn't you try it?) but you can also just write `return number >= 0`.

Comment: `not bool(number)` is the same as `not number`.

Comment: You can use the operator with "return" but the "bool" conversion can be a problem if "number" can be negative or a float but this is not related to "return" in particular.

Comment: Your code reports that 0 is positive, by the way. (In case you weren't aware, 0 is not positive.)

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but generally there's no point in defining trivial functions like this. It's a lot easier to read and write `if number > 0` than `if is_positive(number)`.

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong in asking the question that I got three downvotes I can't even ask another question now

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

But a better code would look like that:

```
def is_positive(number):
    return (number > 0)
```

Your code returns `True` if `number == 0`, even if it enters the `else` section, since `bool(number)` always return `True` if `number != 0`.
If you want that, use `>=` instead of `>`.

In your code, you're calculating two boolean values, while one is enough. You're calculating a boolean `number > 0`, and if it is `True`, you're calculating a new boolean that will always be `True` if the first condition is valid, and same for the `else` statement, so it's like writing:

```
def is_positive(number):
    if number > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Now you can see more clearly that if `number > 0` is `True`, it returns `True`, and if `number > 0` is `False`, it returns `False`.
But `number > 0` is by itself a boolean statement that evaluates to `True` and `False`. For example, if you know `number > 0`, your code is equivalent to:

```
def is_positive(number):
    if True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And if not:

```
def is_positive(number):
    if False:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

So as you can see, you can directly return `number > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can. `bool` function will return `true` with any number except zero (even negative one). But this code is not good. you can do it in many better ways. The best way is to do it like this.

```
def is_positive(number):
    return (number > 0)
```

If is a statement that does this: If the condition was true do this else do that. In your code, it is like this: if the condition was true, return true else return false. So you can simply say return the answer of the condition instead of saying if it was true return true. if the number is positive, the answer to `number > 0`  will become true so it's simply like to say return true and if not, the answer to the condition will become false so it's like to say return false. Actually, when you call this method, it will check the condition first. if it was true, it is replaced with true and if not, it is replaced with false.

Comment: does it automatically do the if for you

Comment: @AbhishekSamuel No, the `if` is unnecessary.

Comment: @AbhishekSamuel if is a statement that does this: If the condition was true do this else do that. In your code, it is like this: if the condition was true, return true else return false. So you can simply say return the answer of the condition instead of saying if it was true return true. if the number is positive, the answer to `number > 0`  will become true so it's simply like to say return true and if not, the answer to the condition will become false so it's like to say return false.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot! Syntactically speaking, you can: the program will compile. However, it will work differently than you think.

Every number except for a zero converted into a `bool` gives `True`.

Comment: Mhm, you're right, sorry. I'll edit that. However, I still feel like there is misunderstanding in what `bool` return for negative numbers.